# Replace value of formula in same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a function in Excel that can do the following for me:

Suppose we have a column in Excel:

```
Column A:
row 1: sdjfj - bla
row 2: spsj - bla
row 3: okok - hey
row 4: isjf - bla
row 5: kf - okok
```

I want the result of Column A to be Column A'

```
Column A':
row 1: bla
row 2: bla
row 3: okok - hey
row 4: bla
row 5: kf - okok
```

So that I just replace the strings with the last three letters being bla IN THE SAME COLUMN. I have been looking at substitute function and replace function, but I haven't been able to figure it out how to apply it to my situation, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't use a worksheet formula to replace a value in the same cell - that would create a circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the easiest solution is to put this super simple formula into column 'B', then, copy the result and paste as values back into column 'A'.

> '=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)="bla","bla",A1)'

Alternatively this vba sub will do it in one step.

```
    Sub bla_bla_bla()
Dim CL As Range
Dim RG As Range
Set RG = Range("A1:A" & (Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1))
RG.Select
For Each CL In RG.Cells
    If Right(CL.Value, 3) = "bla" Then
        CL.Value = "bla"
    End If
Next CL
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much just what I was looking for :-)